# How hide helm buffers in *Buffer-List*?

Tags: helm, buffers

windows 10, emacs 26.1, helm 3.0

Here my buffer list:

[image]

How I can hide all **helm** buffers? I'm don't want to Emacs to show them in ***Buffer List*** ?

Comment: Use `ibuffer`...

Answer (score 3):

Helm comes with its own buffer listing commands that exclude helm buffers. Try `M-x helm-buffers-list` or `M-x helm-mini` (does the same, but adds more sources, like recently closed files).

Comment: Suppose I open 10 buffers. If I can use prev-buffer (C-x left) / next-buffer (C-x right) to go to prev/next buffers. It's very comfortable.

But I need when I do this to skip some buffers. E.g. buffers whose names start with helm-xxx.

Is it possible?

Comment: That's a different question, but see my answer

Comment: ...see my answer to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44697/how-to-skip-some-buffers-when-use-prev-buffer-next-buffer